# sqlite remove non utf-8 characters

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, ascii

I have an sqlite db that has some crazy ascii characters in it and I would like to remove them, but I have no idea how to go about doing it.  I googled some stuff and found some people saying to use REGEXP with mysql, but that threw an error saying REGEXP wasn't recognized.

Here is the error I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'table_name' with text ...
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you sure you want to get rid of "crazy" characters? Learning how to deal with all unicode characters is actually kind of fun...

Comment: so are they ASCII characters or UTF-8? Since your are using SQLAlchemy, it is already handling UTF-8 just fine, but you are probably confused about what to do with it once you get it. http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Comment: ~unutbu: depends on your definition of "fun" ;) I'd certainly call it "useful" and "initially daunting", and "worthwhile" but "fun" never crossed my mind.

Comment: I would love to learn how, and I hate to be douchy but I am under a tight deadline right now.  Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: @msw no they are non-ascii characters (i think).  SQLAlchemy throws an error on the select statement.  I'm not even doing anything with the characters yet.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but it's not even clear to me what you're asking for. Do you want to remove all non-ascii characters from the column's UTF-8 value, or all characters that are not in the printable ascii range?

Comment: You need to show more code. Don't tell us it threw an error, show us.

Comment: The title refers to "non utf-8 characters". Is that the problem? The table is being treated as utf-8, but it is in some other encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really want to shoehorn a rich unicode string into a plain ascii string 
(and don't mind some goofs), you could use this:

```
import unicodedata as ud
def shoehorn_unicode_into_ascii(s):
    # This removes accents, but also other things, like ß‘’“”
    return ud.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

For a more complete solution (with somewhat fewer goofs, but requiring a third-party module [unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1)), [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854230/whats-the-fastest-way-to-strip-and-replace-a-document-of-high-unicode-characters).

Really, though, the best solution is to work with unicode data throughout your code as much as possible, and drop to an encoding only when necessary.

Comment: I was actually looking for an sql statement I could use then I don't have to deal with it.  I actually already tried this function: def removeNonAscii(s): return "".join(i for i in s if ord(i)<128) and I still get the error because it's happening when I do the select in SQLAlchemy I think.

Comment: @bababa: Can you draw out the text with a simple SQL SELECT statement like `SELECT * from table` ? If so, it would not be hard to write a one-off script to read in the data, and use `UPDATE`s to write back ascii data... Very low-brow, but expedient.